# Entity framework - Include() loads all chidren properties even virtual ones

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first

I am trying to build a model with Entity Framework - Code First in which I use a "Exam" class and a "Subject" class that have a many-to-many relationship.

A "Exam" contains a list of "Subject" (Subjects). 

A "Subject" contains a list of "Exam" (Exams).

Both "Exams" and "Subjects" are virtual properties.

When I use `context.Exams.Include("Subjects").ToList();`, I get all the exams and all the subjects related to each exam, which is OK. The problem is I also get all the exams related to the subjects.

Result :

1. Exam 1

   - Subject 1

     - *Exam 3*
     - *Exam 4*
   - Subject 2

     - *Exam 3*
2. Exam 2
   ...

In this particular case, I don't need the exams related to the subjects. I just need the following data :

1. Exam 1

   - Subject 1
   - Subject 2
2. Exam 2
   ...

> **Is there a way to include "Subjects" but without the "Exams" property ?**

Thank you.

*Function*

```
public List<Exam> GetAllExams()
    {
        using (var context = new PedagogieContext())
        {
            return context.Exams.Include("Subjects").ToList();
        }
    }
```

*Classes*

```
public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ExamLabel { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SubjectLabel { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}
```

*Mappings*

```
class SubjectMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Subject>
{
    public SubjectMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        this.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("KeyDiscipline");
        this.Property(e => e.SubjectLabel).HasColumnName("DisciplineLib");
        this.ToTable("vpDisciplines");
    }
}

class ExamMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Exam>
{
    public ExamMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        this.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("KeyExamen");
        this.Property(e => e.ExamenLabel).HasColumnName("ExamenLib");
        this.ToTable("vExamens");

        this.HasMany(e => e.Subjects)
            .WithMany(d => d.Exams)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("vrExamensDisciplines");
                m.MapLeftKey("KeyExamen");
                m.MapRightKey("KeyDiscipline");
            });

    }
}
```

*Context*

```
public class PedagogieContext : DbContext
{
    public PedagogieContext()
        : base(ConnectionStringManager.GetConnectionString())
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExamMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubjectMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure `LazyLoading` is disabled.

Comment: Are you sure that sub-exams had loaded? They are lazy-loading entities, so EF can load them later and absolutely transparently.

Comment: I tried to disable LazyLoading, but I still get the sub-exams.

Comment: Try to get the SQL query that EF prepares for you. `context.Exams.Include("Subjects").ToString()` will give you real `SELECT`. Does it include sub-exams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that Entity Framework executes *relationship fixup* whenever you get data from the database (and on many more occasions). This is the process where EF automatically populates navigation properties (like `Subject.Exams`) of entities in its cache.

You are fetching exams and subjects and EF kindly populates their `Subjects` *and* `Exams`, respectively. There is no way to stop EF from doing this (some may think that setting `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` will do that, but no).

Note that you don't get more exams from the database than you get from the query, if that's what you're worried about. It's just that EF also creates the associations. In a debug view you could expand the collections endlessly without ever hitting the database.

The solution is not to display `Subject.Exams`. If this is for serialization, you have to block circular references. Some serializers (like Json.Net) have settings to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers. 
Indeed, entity framework doesn't load more exams than expected. It just populates the sub-exams with the exams already loaded. 
My problem was actually a circular reference serializer issue. 
I chose to use DTO (with automapper) to specify exactly the data I need in my view.

http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-getting-started/